# How do you handle hallucinations/daydreaming in comics?

Tags: creative-writing, comics

How do you handle hallucinations/daydreaming in comics? I remember instances where people in TV shows are literally dreaming while awake with their eyes wide-open and just wakes up from their daydreaming or hallucination in complete shock. How do you handle these scenes in comics without wasting too many panels trying to depict this? Do you have some examples? I tried to search for some examples over the Internet, but I couldn't find anything at all.

Comment: One example of (drug-induced) hallucination: https://www.thecomicstrips.com/comic-strip/Mike+du+Jour/2017-01-29/152944 Hallucination is probably easier to do that plain daydreaming, because you can use trippy colors and distortions.

Comment: A great example of daydreaming in comics is [this Calvin and Hobbes strip](https://i.pinimg.com/originals/a4/52/13/a4521398378797a894a6efc48d0cbb27.gif). While it's not a comic, you may also want to look up the British TV series *Reggie Perrin*, where the main character regularly has daydreams that last only a few seconds before snapping back to reality.

Answer (score 1):

You could change the style of whatever objects you want the character/characters to hallucinate to save space. Or just change the colouring, Make the things that are being hallucinated opaquer or like see through.